# ASP.NET Core populate selectlist with union result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
  var a = _context.Components.Select(c => c.Week).Union(_context.FinishGoods.Select(f => f.Week));
  WeekFilter = new SelectList(a, "Week", "Week");
```

this does not work. What do i need to make the union result work on select list? I Tried ToList(), AsEnumerable()

this has worked

```
   Entries = _con.Query<ExcelViewModel>(query).ToList();


    var selectList = Entries                
        .Select(e => new
    {
        Id = e.ComponentWeek.Value.ToString(),
        Name = e.ComponentWeek.Value.ToString()
    }
    ).Union(Entries.Select(e => new
    {
        Id = e.FinishGoodWeek.Value.ToString(),
        Name = e.FinishGoodWeek.Value.ToString(),
    }));

    WeekFilter = new SelectList(selectList, "Id", "Name");
```

**EDIT**

here are the objects to union they are basically the same in structure

```
  public class FinishGood
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        public int? Week { get; set; }
        public int EntryId { get; set; }
        public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    }



 public class Component
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        public int? Week { get; set; }

        public int EntryId { get; set; }
        public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Show the `c.Week` object.

Comment: updated the post with the objects

Comment: I have Edited the answer please try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one it works fine.

```
var a = _context.Components.Select(c => new { Week = c.Week.Value })
            .Union(_context.FinishGoods.Select(f => new { Week = f.Week.Value })).ToList();

WeekFilter = new SelectList(a, "Week" , "Week");
```

Comment: just null exception, I changed this to get Week.Value since Week is an `int?` that might have been the issue

Comment: But in the shown object `FinishGood` and  `Component` `Week` as int and required not nullable.

Comment: ah sorry, i forgot i was using view model i will edit this